# simulation to fit logistic with different proportion

Tags: r

I am a new R user, I am trying to do a simulation study to fit a logistic model with different missing proportions. I have tried some code but it does not give me any output, can someone help me?

```
p=c(.03,0.2,0.6) #proportion of missingness
for(i in 1:length(p)){
mcar<-prodNA(dd,noNA=0.2)# function to impose missingness
mis.fit=glm(y~x1+x2+x3, family = "binomial",data=mcar)
mis.fit
mis.bias=t(coef(mis.fit))-t(coef(comp.fit))
mis.bias
mis.sum=summary(mis.fit)
mis.sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reproduce your problem: you did not mention the `missForest` package and we do not know what `dd` is.

My guess is that you could benefit from using `print()` in your loop

For example

```
i <- 5
i^2
```

gives

```
[1] 25
```

but

```
for (i in 1:5){
 i^2
}
```

gives no visible output

while

```
for (i in 1:5){
  print(i^2)
}
```

gives

```
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
[1] 25
```

Comment: dd is my data frame

Comment: @M.Salim Yes - but we cannot reproduce your problem because we do not have your data.  What would improve your question is an small example we can run to see what you get, plus a statement of what you would like to see.  Meanwhile I suggest you try replacing your line `mis.fit`  with a line `print(mis.fit)` and see whether that changes what happens